# When is the Lebesgue measure of a set zero?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $l^n$ be the Lebesgue measure on $ \sigma$-algebra $L^n$ of Lebesgue measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A\in L^n$.
Suppose there exists an open covering $\{A_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ with finite $\sum_{i=1}^\infty l^n(A_i)$ and $A\subset A_i$ for infinitely many $i$.

> How do I show that $l^n(A)=0$?

I really appreciate any hints as where to start, since I don't know how to begin.
I do know that
$$l^n(X)=\sup\{l^n(C):C\subset X,C\text{ compact}\}=\inf\{l^n(O):X\subset O,O\text{ open}\}$$
and I think this must be used.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Hint. The measure of $A$ must be less than or equal to the measure of $A_i$ infinitely often. What do you know about the sequence of measures of $A_i$?

Comment: If $A \subset A_i$ for all $i$, then $$\sum_{i = 1}^k l^n(A_i) \geqslant k\cdot l^n(A).$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: recall that if a series of positive numbers is finite, then the sequence converges to zero.

Comment: I think I see what you mean, but I'm not sure yet. From the comments above I see that $l^n(A)\leq\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^kl^n(A_i)$. So $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^kl^n(A_i)=0$, since $\sum_{i=1}^\infty l^n(A_i)$ is finite. Is that all there is to the proof?